# Does Ubuntu log events occurring during the boot?

Tags: installation, boot, log

Is there anywhere in the ubuntu (or linux in general) logs which can record a computer booting up and the OS failing to load, due to a problem encountered during the boot stage?

Answer (score 6):

you can check it into

**/var/log**

This directory has all types of logs

/var/log/auth.log

```
Record of all logins and logouts by normal users and system processes.
```

/var/log/btmp

```
Log of all attempted bad logins to the system. Accessed via the lastb command.
```

/var/log/debug

```
Debugging output from various packages.
```

/var/log/dmesg

```
Kernel ring buffer. The content of this file is referred to by the dmesg command.
```

/var/log/gdm/

```
GDM log files. Normally a subset of the last X log file. See /var/log/xdm.log for mode details.
```

/var/log/kdm.log

```
KDM log file. Normally a subset of the last X log file. See /var/log/xdm.log for more details.
```

/var/log/messages

```
System logs.
```

/var/log/pacct

```
Process accounting is the bookkeeping of process activity. The raw data of process activity is maintained here. Three commands can be used to access the contents of this file dump-acct, sa (summary of process accounting) and lastcomm (list the commands executed on the system).
```

/var/log/utmp

```
Active user sessions. This is a data file and as such it can not be viewed normally. A human-readable form can be created via the dump-utmp command or through the w, who or users commands.
```

/var/log/wtmp

```
Log of all users who have logged into and out of the system. The last command can be used to access a human readable form of this file. It also lists every connection and run-level change.
```

/var/log/xdm.log

```
XDM log file. Normally subset of the last X startup log and pretty much useless in light of the details the X logs is able to provide us with. Only consult this file if you have XDM specific issues otherwise just use the X logfile.
```

/var/log/XFree86.0.log, /var/log/XFree86.?.log

```
X startup logfile. An excellent resource for uncovering problems with X configuration. Log files are numbered according to when they were last used. For example, the last log file would be stored in /var/log/XFree86.0.log, the next /var/log/XFree86.9.log, so on and so forth.
```

/var/log/syslog

```
The 'system' log file. The contents of this file is managed via the syslogd daemon which more often than not takes care of all log manipulation on most systems.
```

Comment: Can you just confirm if i turned on my box and the OS didn't load up because, say a hardware fault, this would be captured in one of the logs above? Is messages.log the one which would record this?

Comment: @davide not every time... if it is grub or the hdd or somethign with a cable that is the problem you will get an on-screen message. This will not be recorded into a log file.

Comment: @Rinzwind, would something be captured to show that the startup did not succeed?

Comment: @david nope. Unless you get a digital camera and make a pixs yourself. But those errors are very rare.

Answer (score 4):

While I'll find Shekhar Raut answer correct, I think the list could be a bit shorther.

Since OP is asking about booting and nothing else - kernel logs in Linux (in general) can be found at:

```
/var/log/messages
```

So, if you have a boot failure due to some hardware problem, this should be the first place   to look at.

**Update:**

Looks like Ubuntu removed this log file since 12.04 (not confirmed), and now the right place to look for the system logs is:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Comment: there is no such file in ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 (AFAIK), there is `/var/log/boot.log`, which logs the output from early boot.

Comment: That doesen't contain all the information that was written during boot

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/log/kern.log
```

contains the logs produced by the kernel during boot. after boot there is nearly no event added but you will see the uptime on each entry